# VS Code + Vim -- Enter insert mode on click

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

As I am gradually getting used to the Vim extension in VS code, I find myself falling back quite often to using the mouse.

Is there a setting I can configure so that whenever I use the mouse to click and move my cursor, vim will automatically switch to insert mode?

If I didn't want to switch to insert mode, I wouldn't see myself using the mouse in the first place. So this setting makes sense for me.